# What's closed in Belgium on New Year's Eve/Day?

Tags: netherlands, belgium, public-holidays

What businesses in Belgium are open on Dec. 31 and Jan. 1?

We plan to visit the Netherlands and Belgium from Dec 25 through Jan 5.  We'll be in Belgium on Dec. 31 and Jan. 1. How much will holiday closures affect us? In particular, what will be closed on Dec. 31 and Jan. 1 (or limited, e.g. reduced hours, reduced schedule, reduced ticket-sellers)? Specifically: Will we be able to buy train and bus tickets? Buying groceries? Will restaurants be open Jan. 1?

Comment: Dutch cities have a special tradition: fireworks. Not a some firework display organized by the municipality but insane amount of fireworks on each street corner (Germany is a bit like that too). I think we had another question about that recently.

Comment: Dec 31 is no holiday in Belgium, so things could be open. Jan 1 is, so expect nothing to be open.

Comment: If places close for two days in the Netherlands it is mostly 25th of December and 1st of January, if three days also 26 December. And most museums will be closed those days, shops might be open but do not expect to spend a full day shopping at Christmas, it is not going to happen.